# Notification when user uninstalls Android app

Tags: android, mobile, android-manifest

Is there a way to get notification when a user uninstalls my app from his/her android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can get the other applications uninstall events using the PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast receiver but not the application uninstalled itself (because it have been removed) see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no way since, as far as I know, there are no callbacks into your app when the app is uninstalled from the device.