# kendo ui mobile. Event that fires when user uninstalls app

Tags: telerik, local-storage, kendo-mobile

Our app is storing quite a few items in the user's local storage.   Call me crazy but I'd like to do some clean up once the user uninstalls the app( clear my local storage items, etc..).

I can't seem to find any documentation/events that fire when the user attempts to uninstall the app.  I could be wrong but I don't think local storage items get cleared.

-Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at least in Android, there is no good way for an app to do anything on uninstall.

See also:

[Notification when user uninstalls Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231853/notification-when-user-uninstalls-android-app)

[Perform a task on uninstall in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)